# Powershell Regex groups

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to get the path of an installed application from a string using Regex but can't understand the results I'm seeing.

My string includes the path I want to find "C:\GPONew\XPP\xz\bin" and out of that I want to capture the "C:\GPONew\XPP" and to test the script I'm testing for "\xz***X***\bin" to give a false result:

```
$path = "C:\GPONew\XPP\Perl\site\bin;C:\GPONew\XPP\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\GPONew\XPP\xz\bin"
$path -match "([A-Z]{1}:\\[^;]*\\XPP)\\xzX\\bin"
$Matches
```

And this outputs False for $Matches but does give me capture groups which I don't understand as it shouldn't match with the extra X in "xz".

```
False

Name                           Value                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                               
1                              C:\GPONew\XPP                                                                                                                       
0                              C:\GPONew\XPP\xz\bin
```

On top of this, the docs [Groups, Captures, and Substitutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7#groups-captures-and-substitutions) go on to say that I can address $Matches using any hashtable method to access the value stored.

$Matches.0 or $Matches.1 but this gives me the error:

```
Unexpected token '.0' in expression or statement.
+ $Matches.0 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (.0:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

And I have to instead use $Matches[0]

I am though using Powershell V 2.0 if that makes a difference?

**EDIT:**

After Wiktor Stribiżew's comment I closed my ISE down and opened it back up again and no longer get any matches with a False match but as soon as I change the match so it is True and then change it back so that it is false, I continue to get matches even if I have the following:

```
clear
$path = "C:\GPONew\XPP\Perl\site\bin;C:\GPONew\XPP\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\GPONew\XPP\xz\bin"
$path -match "([A-Z]{1}:\\[^;]*\\XPP)\\xzABC\\bin"
clear
$Matches
```

Output

```
False

Name                           Value                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                               
1                              C:\GPONew\XPP                                                                                                                       
0                              C:\GPONew\XPP\xz\bin
```

[image: Screenshot showing Matches even though I'm clearing]

Comment: I get an empty `$Matches`  output - are you sure you ran your code in a clean console?

Comment: Odd, I was typing clear in the the console then also added clear at the first line and was still getting matches. Closed the ISE down and opened again and now I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking what `clear` does. That cmdlet only clears the screen, not variables. If you want to clear out the contents of the automatic variable `$Matches` you will want to use `Clear-Variable Matches` instead. What you are seeing is expected behavior.

Comment: Fabulous, thank you. I was indeed mistaking what clear did!

Comment: If this answer solves the issue please use the checkmark to the left to mark it as accepted to help future users with similar issues find functional answers more quickly.